# jQuery fails to set the width of a div on first load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a [site](https://sampolahti.github.io/harri/) for my friend, where the fixed footer should have a margin of the size of the big picture (that's used as a menu). I also want the content div to have the same margin. But for some reason when I first load the page, content div and the footer don't have any margin at all. When I re-load the page, everything works perfectly... But I want it to work on the initial loading of the page. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var mainPicWidth = $('#navimg').width();
var mainPicWidth2 = mainPicWidth - 10;
$('#footer').css('margin-left', mainPicWidth2)
$('#content').css('margin-left', mainPicWidth)

var wholePageWidth = $('#content').width() + 15;
$('#footer').css('width', wholePageWidth)
```

I also have the follow part as means of making the site responsive. Could this conflict with my previous code somehow?

```
$(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
    if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
    window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
    this.location.reload(false); /* false to get page from cache */
    }, 100);
});

if ($(window).width() <= 1100) {
    $('#footer').css('width', "100%")
    $('#footer').css('margin-left', "0")
    $('#content').css('margin-left', "0")
    });
}

if ($(document.body).height() != $("*").height()) {
    $('#footer').css('position', 'fixed')
    $('#footer').css('bottom', '0')
} else {
    $('#footer').css('position', 'relative')
}
```

Comment: Try to wait on window load, that way all the images should have been fully loaded, so the size is detectable.

Comment: everything you try to achieve could be done with plain css. why are you using javascript instead?